# Cant show book covers only URLs

Tags: javascript, url

I have a json file with some books information. Im trying to display the book covers but I only get to display the URLs to the covers. Please help!

```
function fillBookShelf() {

    var bookShelf = document.getElementById('bookShelf');
    bookShelf.innerHTML = ' ';

    for (var i = 0; i < bookList.length; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        var cover = bookList[i].portada;
        var bigCover = bookList[i].detalle;
        var language = bookList[i].idioma;
        var title = bookList[i].titulo;
        var description = bookList[i].descripcion;

        var book = document.createElement('div');

        book.append(cover);
        bookShelf.append(book);        
    }


}
```

Comment: cover is the url? so you need to add an image with cover as its src.

Comment: yes...cover is the url. I have already tried that...but didnt work. Maybe im doing it wrong....Ill try again. Thank you!

Comment: `var book = document.createElement('div');
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = cover;
book.append(image);
bookShelf.append(book);   `

Comment: @dfsq you are a genius! thank you very much!